# Bootcamp Partition Erased and Partition is Gone (Now it's FREE SPACE)

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I removed my Bootcamp Partition and now I suddenly lost about 75GB of space on my Macintosh HD drive. I had 256GB of internal default storage; now I have about 174GB. Bootcamp partition does not show up on disk utility. In the terminal disk lit below, you can see it under "/dev/disk0" that it doesn't even have a disk number or identifier. It's literally just "(free space)". HELP! I need to *reunite* the partitions into a normal 256GB storage.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         174.9 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot ⁨Boot OS X⁩               134.2 MB   disk0s3
                    (free space)                         75.7 GB    -

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +174.9 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            14.9 GB    disk1s1
   2:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 14.9 GB    disk1s1s1
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 288.3 MB   disk1s2
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                655.5 MB   disk1s3
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩     151.9 GB   disk1s6

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk3⁩         1.5 TB     disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk4⁩         500.0 GB   disk2s3

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.5 TB     disk3
                                 Physical Store disk2s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Samsung Y3 Media⁩        526.5 GB   disk3s1

/dev/disk4 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk4
                                 Physical Store disk2s3
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨TIME MACHINE⁩            133.8 GB   disk4s2
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not need `disk0s3`. You can remove the partition with the command given below.

```
diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3
```

The free space can now be added to the APFS container by using the command given below.

```
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
```

Comment: Oh I just made a time machine backup and then deleted my entire drive and got the 250GB back!